# Is it possible to identify a BLE device that is sending random addresses?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing some code that scans for BLE devices. Because of the address type random the same device may send out multiple address if its GAP address type is Random. Is there a way to determine if different addresses came from the same device?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible after bonding the devices. While bonding, devices using a random address share a resolvable key with wich one can determine wether a received random address matches a known device or not. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61660118/get-ble-mac-from-random-private-resolvable-address) question.

Comment: Is there a Gatt api or a Windows DeviceInfomation call that can retrieve the public address after a successful bonding?

Comment: I would assume the [id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.id?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Devices_Enumeration_DeviceInformation_Id) to stay the same, even if the resolvable random address changes. But I honestly never worked with BLE on windows before

Comment: I agree but the Windows BLE api seems very opaque to me when compared to MacOS/iOS, Linux and Android.